# How to redirect the perl -nle command to a file?

Tags: perl, shell

I need redirect the below command to a file.

```
ping -i 10 host | perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_'
```

I have trying with > output.txt and >> output.txt and It doesn't working.

Tks.

Comment: can you show the exact code that isn't working? Where did you put the redirect operators?

Comment: ping -i 10 www.uol.com.br | perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_' >> /tmp/ping_uol_10secs.txt

Comment: How are you stopping the `ping` process? Does it work if you modify the `ping` to: `ping -c 5 -i 10 host`

Comment: @AlexandrePinheiro:  Your command looks correct.  I think you're running afoul of buffering.

Comment: If the `host` isn't valid, `ping` reports to STDERR leaving your script with nothing. `ping -i 10 host 2>&1 | perl ...`

Comment: Can you define "it doesn't work"? I tried the exact line you posted in the comment and it runs (finishes executing) just fine.

Comment: @doubleDown:  I _think_ Alexandre is trying to generate a running log out to a file.  But, since it pings only once every 10 seconds, and the output of the perl script is so minimal, the log file only updates every several minutes.  To make this work as expected (ie. the log updates w/out buffering), you need to set STDOUT to be unbuffered, or modify the script to print to STDERR and capture stderr to a file.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Hi All, I'm sure that I can be more clear: 1.ping -i 10 host >> output.txt   It's ok!!  2.ping -i 10 host | perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_'  (console) It's ok!!   3.ping -i 10 host | perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_' >> output.txt  It's not ok! Doesn't works! The output.txt file is empty!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If modifying your command to make sure `ping` finished properly, and not with `<ctrl-c>` for example.

```
ping -c 5 -i 10 host | perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_' > output.txt
```

Then it really sounds like a buffering issue. Which you can turn off in `perl` with `$| = 1`.

```
ping -i 10 host | perl -nle '$|++; print scalar(localtime), " ", $_' > output.txt
```